# Running bash loop

Tags: command-line, bash

I've created a while loop in a bash script to run a couple of PHP commands. The reason why I've created the while loop is because I can't use cronjobs (I don't want to create a new instance of the bash script while the other one is still running).

Previously I ran the command using screen but it seems eventually my resources were all eating up by this process.

So my question is; what is a good alternative to run the bash script?

Script is similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting daemon.."

while true; do
   echo "Running runJobs.."
   cd /var/www/wiki && nice -n 10 /usr/bin/php maintainAll.php maintainwiki runJobs >> /var/log/runJobs.log
   echo "Sleeping 60 seconds.."
   sleep 60
done
```

Comment: [What are you trying to accomplish?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: A script that runs php scripts forever.

Comment: I think l0b0 meant: What do you want to do with "running PHP scripts forever"? How are you going to use that?

Comment: As @edwin said, It depends on you applications/objectives. For in my case when I want to run a script which infinite loop with lower cpu resource, I use `sleep` command to make delays and `renice` processes to a lower priority after I launch them in background using `&`.

Comment: Its for running maintenance scripts

Comment: +1 for using sleep. can we see the script?

Comment: See last edit..

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to let PHP do the looping, rather than doing a looped call to PHP.

Really, as soon as you have that, all you need to do then is have Ubuntu keep a copy of the script running in some form. That can be accomplished with a super-simple Upstart script. You could put this in `/etc/init/myphpscript.conf`:

```
description "My PHP script"

start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn

exec sudo -u www-data -- php -f /path/to/script.php
```

Note that as soon as PHP exits, Upstart is going to pump out another copy so if you don't put a sleep in the PHP, you'll be in a very quick, possibly very expensive (I don't know what your code does) loop.